# Using filter_horizontal, is there a way to control what is displayed on the widget?

Tags: django

When I use the filter_horizontal in Django, the filter creates a widget with the model primary-key names. However, I want to display something different, such as a name field. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I figured it out. Just override the `__str__` method of the model to return your model name or whatever.